# Android dialog title custom XML layout height

Tags: android, android-layout

I use this code for custom dialog title XML-layout

```
 public class UtilityDialog extends Dialog
 {
  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
....
....
....
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.dialog_title);
  setContentView(content);
  }
 }
```

it works but height of title is too small and it does not contains any UI element of 
 R.layout.dialog_title

[image]

R.layout.dialog_title-->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Cellalert" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You use a fixed height on your layout: `android:layout_height="65dip"`. Did you tried to use `wrap_content` instead?

Comment: i used wrap_content but still not working

Comment: I was unable to get solution of this problem. so finally i use setConevtView(View) to set view of whole dialog..
hope someone will get solution for this.